# Why the first code works on the server, but the second one doesnt

Tags: php, email, post, cpanel

The first code without $_Post works, the second one with $_POST doesnt. It is on the server in cpanel. Anything helps :)

I tried various things like changing the code in HTML, placing slashes, also using $_request over $_post.

This works -

```
$to_email = "example@example.hr";
$subject = "Simple Email Test via PHP";
$body = "Hi,nn This is test email send by PHP Script";
$headers = "From: me@example.hr";
if ( mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)){
    echo("Email successfully sent to $to_email...");
} else {
    echo("Email sending failed...");
}

$to_email = "example@example.hr";
$subject = "Simple Email Test via PHP";
$body = "Poruka:$_POST[poruka]";
$headers = "From: $_POST[email]\n"; 
if ( mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)){
    echo("Email successfully sent to $to_email...");
} else {
    echo("Email sending failed...");
}
</code></pre>
```

The first code sends the email, while the second one goes into echo ("Email sending failed...")

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: The 2nd example has an extra `\n` in the `$headers` variable.

Comment: This is not so nice: `"Poruka:$_POST[poruka]"`

Comment: it says, Email sending failed...array(4) { ["name"]=> string(3) "123" ["email"]=> string(13) "123@gmail.com" ["poruka"]=> string(3) "123" ["sumbit"]=> string(8) "Pošalji" } @barmar

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` so you'll see the reason why sending failed.

Comment: @Barmar it just says the webpage not working if i add error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: What i know is that everything gets executed but the problem occurs when i enter into mail() function, and the people from cpanel say that the function works on the server just not in this code

Comment: Try getting rid of the `\n` at the end of `$headers`. That seems to be the only significant difference between the two versions.

Comment: Still does not work, I think the problem might be in the cpanel setting somehow, i just dont understand where